# Are magical stat bonuses working in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just got a magic item that grants +5 to dexterity...however, when I equip it on my wizard, my dexterity stays at its base 17, and none of the other stats shown under "details" changes either.

Is the bonus not being correctly applied?

Comment: Since you accepted LessPop's answer, did you figure out what the actual problem was?

Comment: I now have, see my comment on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested some Str, Int, and Dex items on my Demon Hunter and they're working fine. All three stats are properly applied. So while I have no idea what your issue is, we can rule out a generalized "stats are broken" statement.

Comment: As it turns out, the item was working correctly, but just lifting the item out of its position doesn't turn off its effects while it's on your mouse pointer. You have to place the item into your inventory to turn off its effects.